# How to extract text from PDF using iTextSharp version 4.1.6?

Tags: c#, parsing, pdf, itext, pdftotext

I want to use older version of iTextSharp as it comes with LGPL license.
but I don't know the method used in older version to read text from PDF.
I have used version 5.5 previously and know the method for that version.
here I want specific version info to get text out of PDF.

Comment: Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Forget about getting text with 4.1.6, that was an area where it did really improve in later versions.

Comment: As Paulo already hints, the correct answer to your question is: *no*.

Comment: Make sure you don't introduce versions older than iText 5 in commercial software offered to customers. See [Can iText 2.1.7 / iTextSharp 4.1.6 or earlier be used commercially?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5) for more info. Don't expect an answer on your question. I will vote to close it as a problem that no longer exists (because it works in version 5.5). What you're asking is the equivalent of "I can see colors on my color TV, but I now want to switch to an old black&white TV. Why don't I see colors on that TV?"

Comment: Thank you @poke for referring to that answer. I forgot all about it. I edited it because I am no longer the CEO of the company. I am now the CTO.

Comment: @PauloSoares I want to use 4.1.6 because of LGPL